# What is the maximum limit of data that can be written on SSL socket in one shot in java?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, io

I am writing about 10000 bytes on SSL socket in one shot by  taking OutputStream instance from it

```
OutputStrem os = ssl_Socket.getOutputStream();
```

os is OutputStream here. It writes the data successfully to the server, but the data received at server end is getting corrupted somehow.

But If I use BufferedOutputStream everthing works fine.

```
os = new BufferedOutputStream(c._s.getOutputStream(), 8196);
```

My Question :

1. Is there any limit on data that can be written on SSL socket in one shot ?
   Is there any default buffer size ?
2. Why it worked successfully with BufferedOutputStream ? Since I have to write large chunk of data I don't want to use BufferedOutputStream ?

Comment: How is that data corrupted exactly? How do you read it on the other side?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any limit on data that can be written on SSL socket in one shot?

There is no limit other than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. The `SSLSocket`'s output stream will block until all the data has been sent, including encryption and packaging into the requisite number of underlying SSL records.

> Is there any default buffer size?

`BufferedOutputStream` has a default buffer size of 8192. 8196 is a curious number to use for a buffer size, but you should certainly always use a buffered stream or writer over an `SSLSocket`'s output stream. Otherwise you can get a data explosion of up to 42 times, if you write a byte at a time

> Why it worked successfully with BufferedOutputStream ? Since I have to write large chunk of data I don't want to use BufferedOutputStream?

You don't have to use a `BufferedOutputStream`, but it doesn't hurt, even if you're writing large chunks of data. The buffer is bypassed when possible.

Your problems are almost certainly at the receiving end.

Comment: I have created a SpyOutputStream that writes data to a file before writing it on server. The data written on file is strangely same

Answer (score -1):

"[TLS] specifies a fixed maximum plaintext fragment length of 2^14 bytes." - which is 16K.

Read about "max_fragment_length" TLS extension which can limit the size of block.

PS: Not familiar with Java SSL library, maybe there is something specific.

Comment: It works fine under 7K, around 10k data is tempered.

Comment: Are you sure that sending side has ended fine (socket closed, all data sent)? Sniff the data at sender and receiver side to see whether all data is transferred.